# Existence of solution for this set of polynomial equations

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations, algebraic-equations

We are given a number $n$ and a vector $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_r)$, where 
$$p_1\geq p_2 \geq \ldots \geq p_r > 0 ; \ \ \ \  \sum_{i\in [r]} p_i \leq 1$$

I'm interested in proving that a solution for the following set of equation exist (the variables here are $t_1,t_2,\ldots, t_r$, all non-negative):
$$\begin{cases} p_i\cdot (1-(1-t_i)^n)\cdot t_{i+1}=p_{i+1}\cdot (1-(1-t_{i+1})^n)\cdot t_{i} & & & &\forall i\in [r-1] \\ 
\sum_{i\in [r]}t_i=1\end{cases}$$

Or equivalently:

$$\begin{cases} p_i\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-t_i)^k\ \ \  =\ \ \  p_{i+1}\cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-t_{i+1})^k  & & & &\forall i\in [r-1]:t_i>0 \\ 
\sum_{i\in [r]}t_i=1\end{cases}$$

So my questions are:

> **1.** Is there always a solution $t$ for this set of equations?
>
> **2.** If not, can we characterize *when* (i.e. for which inputs $n,p$) such solution exist?
>
> **3.** (least important) In which cases such solution can be found efficiently (computationally)?

---

A few observations about this problem:

- If $n=2$, this is gives a set of $r$ linearly-independent linear equations, hence a solution exist and can be found efficiently.
- If $r=2$ (two variables) then this reduces to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187396/does-this-equation-has-a-closed-form-solution-for-t-1-p-sum-i-0nti) (for $p_2=1-p_1$), although now I'm also interested in a solution existence, which is true for $r=2$, but I'm not sure about general $r$. As a result of the discussion on the other question, I believe efficient computation for the general problem would be hard, but I'm wondering what about the *existence* of a solution.

Comment: What is $p_i[1-t_i^n]$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek - the $p_i$'s are given, the $t_i's$ are the variables and I meant the product of $p_i$ and $1 - t_i\ ^n$. I've edited the question, hope this is clear now, thanks.

Comment: Oh I see, so these are just brackets.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek - yes, sorry for the confusion. I also had a mistake copying the equation to the site which is corrected now (replaced $t_i$ and $1-t_i$). Thanks again.

Comment: In your second system, shouldn't there be $(1-t_i)^k$ instead of $(t_i)^k$?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov - true, thanks for the correction !

Comment: You do not mind if some $t_i$ are negative, do you?

Comment: @fedja - Actually in my application I do need all $t_i$'s to be non-negative, I'll add a clarification, thanks !

Comment: @RB: By chance, are you the same poster as for this earlier [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188421/solution-to-system-of-polynomial-equations?noredirect=1#comment471522_188421)?  If you know of a connection between these questions, can you tell us what it is?

Comment: @JasonStarr - I'm not the poster of the question you mention, and I don't see a direct connection. My question is motivated by a game I'm studying, and the solution $t$ of this set of equations would be a symmetric equilibrium in the game ($t_i$ would be the prob. of playing the $i$'th strategy).

Comment: @RB: I posted the wrong link to the wrong question (too many windows open simultaneously)!  Here is the correct [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150117/the-solutions-of-a-system-of-polynomials/150137#150137).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $p_r>0$, your problem has at most a solution *with all* $t_i>0$, and it admits a solution provided the $p_i$'s are not too dispersed, in a sense to be made precise below.

Consider the polynomial $f(t):=\frac{1-(1-t)^n}{t}$. It defines a strictly decreasing homeo $[0,1]\rightarrow [1,n]$ (because it is the incremental ratio of a concave function), and your system writes $p_i f(t_i)=p_{i+1} f(t_{i+1}),$ for $i=1,\dots, r-1$. So it has at most one *strictly positive* solution, given by $t_i=f^{-1}(\lambda/p_i)$, where $\lambda$ solves $$ p_1\le\lambda \le n p_r $$ 
$$\sum_{i=0}^rf^{-1}(\lambda/p_i)=1.$$
Since the LHS in the latter equation is strictly decreasing,  a sufficient condition for existence is then expressed on the $p_i$'s,  requiring
$$ p_1\le  n p_r $$ and
$$\sum_{i=0}^rf^{-1}(np_r /p_i)\le 1 .$$

Comment: Note that assuming $p_r>0$ (hence $p_i>0$ for all $i$) implies that no $t_i$ can vanish, so we didn't loose solutions. If some $p_i$ vanishes, a small discussion is required, but in general uniqueness drops (e.g., if all $p_i$ vanish) .

Comment: I think that $p_r\geq \frac{p_1}{n}$ is what makes sure $t_r$ doesn't vanish, doesn't it? It might also suggest that a solution is still unique, where $t_i=0$ for all $i$ such that $p_i\geq \frac{p_1}{n}$ .

Comment: Actually, consider the following input:
$p_1=p_2=\frac{4}{11}$, $p_3=\frac{3}{11}$ and $n=2$.
This gives us $t_1=t_2=0.5$ and $t_3=0$, despite the fact that $p_3\geq \frac{p_1}{2}$. What am I missing?

Comment: You are right: writing the equations $p_{i}f(t_i) =p_{i+1 }f(t_{i+1}) $ excludes the case where some $t_i$ vanishes.

Comment: So the complete discussion should take into account that some $t_{i_0}$ can be zero. It seems this has a double effect: it makes the ${i_0}$-th equation (and in case $i_0>0$, the ${i_0-1}$-th equation too)  automatically satisfied. Moreover, $p_i f(t_i)$ must be constant only in any interval of $i$ corresponding to non-vanishing $t_i$.

Comment: (I edited and made the minimal changes needed to get a non-incorrect statement. A complete discussion could be made starting from the preceding comment).

Comment: Thanks Pietro. Indeed, the positively values $t_i$ correspond to symmetric equilibrium strategies in a game I'm studying, and $p_if(t_i)$ is the utility of playing strategy $i$ when others play the symmetric strategy, this is why I require that $p_if(t_i)$ will be constant for the strategies in the support of the equilibrium, but if I could identify *when* a solution exist I'll be able to find an equilibrium (or equivalently, the support).

In short, what I'd really like is to characterize is *which* $t_i$'s are positive, given an input vector $p$ (what is the smallest $j$ such that $t_j=0$).

Comment: And we may assume that $p_r>0$ (updated in the question).